# Return private value from contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I need help with returning private string value in smart contract. This value has to be available only to paid account.

I am preloading it inside:

```
static async getInitialProps(props) {

const privateInfo = await itemContract.methods.getPrivateInfo().call()

}
```

Smart contract:

```
string private privateInfo;
mapping(address => bool) public paidAccounts;

...

function getPrivateInfo() public view returns(string) {
  require(paidAccounts[msg.sender] == true); 
  return(privateInfo);
}
```

I keep getting an error **"ERROR: The returned value is not a convertible string:"**
It seems to be working without ***require()***. Is it because I am calling it without paying for a gas, as it has to make calculation "==" ?

Is there any other option to hide private value and show only for paid accounts?

I appreciate for any kind of suggestions or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It's fundamentally impossible to hide data on a public blockchain. Anyone with access to the blockchain can read any data. See https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/02/making-smart-contracts-with-public-variables/.